# P-checkbox with PrimeNg/Angular getting list of selected elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

i'm iterating over an array of elements with p-table

Here is mu HTML

```
    <p-table selectionMode="single" [value]="users" styleClass="p-datatable-customers p-datatable-gridlines p-datatable-striped p-datatable-sm"
        [scrollable]="true" >
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
          <tr>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Selected</th>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-user>
          <tr>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>
              <p-checkbox formControlName="userAdd" name="userAdd" [value]="user"></p-checkbox>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>

      </p-table>
```

In my Ts

```
    createForm(): void {
    this.addUserForm = this.fb.group({
    userAdd: this.fb.control(''),
    });
```

When extracting value of my selected users i use :

```
    const users = this.addUserForm.get('userAdd').value;
```

But i got just one element (the last one)

here is my selected element

```
    value: Array(1)
    0:
    id: 1
    name: "toto"
```

Now i want to retrieve all selected elements in one array.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding [(ngModel)]="selectedValues" in my p-checkbox